# Swift 3: Segue and pass in data from one class to another

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a simple UICollectionViewController called `HomeController` that has a bunch of cells. These cells have a class of their own called `PostCell`. I also have a NSObject class that holds all the data for every `Post` (these posts are my cells). Inside my PostCell I have a `UIView` called `profileSegueContainer`. When I tap this UIView, I want to segue to a new controller. I am able to achieve this with a presentViewController method but I also want to pass in the info of that specific post. For example, if I tap a cell that has the `uid` of "1234", I want to be able to not only segue to the new controller but also pass this uid into it. Of course if I tap the next cell and the `post.uid` of that cell is "4567", then I want to also pass that in when I segue. I hope this makes sense... I want it to work similar to Instagrams "tapped on a user to get to their profile" feature. I hope this makes sense. Any help will be highly appreciated and of course, I will mark as answer. Thank you. All the relevant code is below:

```
class Post: NSObject {

var author: String?
var avatar_image_url: String?
var likes: Int?
var postImageUrl: String?
var uid: String?
var post_id: String?
var hashtags: [String]?
}

class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var postCell: PostCell?
    var userProfileController: UserProfileController?

    var posts = [Post]()

    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = grayBackgroundColor

        self.collectionView?.register(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(16, 0, 16, 0)
        self.collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        self.collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

        setupNavigationBarBranding()
        checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
        fetchPosts()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let frameWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
        let width = frameWidth - (16 + 16)
        let height = frameWidth - (16 / 9) + 50 + 50
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell

        cell.homeController = self
        cell.post = posts[indexPath.item]
        userProfileController?.post = posts[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
}

class PostCell: BaseCell {

var homeController: HomeController?
var userProfileController: UserProfileController?

var post: Post? {
    didSet {

        if let postDisplayName = post?.author {
            displayName.text = postDisplayName
        }

        if let postImageUrl = post?.postImageUrl {
            postImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: postImageUrl)
        }

        if let postProfileImage = post?.avatar_image_url {
            profileImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: postProfileImage)
        }

    }
}

lazy var profileSegueContainer: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return view
    }()

    func handleProfileSegue() {
    let userProfile = UserProfileController()
    let navigationUserProfile = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userProfile)
    homeController?.present(navigationUserProfile, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

    override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfileSegue))
    profileSegueContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

addSubview(profileSegueContainer)

        _ = profileSegueContainer.anchor(profileImage.topAnchor, left: profileImage.leftAnchor, bottom: profileImage.bottomAnchor, right: displayName.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
}
```

Comment: [prepareForSegue(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue)

Comment: @joeybladb could you please explain this? I am not using Storyboards too btw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue has a very specific meaning, in the context of View Controllers. You probably want to use the phrase "push another view controller" instead.

First off, `UINavigationController` is typically only used once in a scene -- it's the view controller that keeps track of a stack of sub-View Controllers. You only create one of them, and you probably want to set your `HomeController` as the nav controller's `rootViewController`.

Then when the user taps the view you should forward this to a method you will add to HomeController; this will create your custom `UserProfile` class, configure it with the data it needs, and then call: `navigationController?.pushViewController(userProfile, animating: true)`

There are many fine tutorials around that show you how this all works.